# Differentiating an integral with respect to the upper bound

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

The professor makes the following calculus :

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{z} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,v-x)dx dv   
$$
Differentiating with respect to z gives :
$$
f_Z (z) =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_{X,Y}(x,z-x)dx
$$
To explain this step, the professor says that differentiating with respect to the upper bound of an integral allows us to replace the x variable by the upper bound. Which if I write it would mean:
$$
\frac{dx}{db} \int_{a}^{b} f(x) dx = f(b)
$$

However I truly don't understand why does this equality hold. Could you give more explanations about this ?

Comment: This is just the Fundamental Theorema of Calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements) and your last formula is wrong. It would be $\frac{d}{db}\int_a^b f(x)dx=f(b)$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, does it also hold for the lower bound of an integral ?

Comment: Recall that $\int_a^b=-\int_b ^a$. Can you figure out what happens?

Comment: If I am not missing something, $$ \frac{d}{db} \int_b^{a} f(x)dx = -f(b) $$  And thus  $$ \frac{d}{da} \int_a^b f(x) dx = -\frac{d}{da} \int_b^a f(x) dx = -f(a) $$

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ! Much appreciated !